# How can i store the value produced by each iteration in a FOR loop when coding in python language?

Tags: python

My code generates a random number.

Here is the code:

```
import random

fixed = "00"

for i in range(5):
    r = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    num = fixed + r
    print(num)
```

So when you run the code it prints 5 different random numbers that start with 00. E.g `001234`.

So the results  will be  something like this:

```
001234
002345
003456
004567
005678
```

Now I want to store each result produced in a variable.

Is it possible? If yes, how do I go about it and if possible how do I write the results to a text file.

I want to store each result as a variable, then append each result in a list and store the list containing the results as text file.

Comment: You can create an empty list at the start and keep appending 'num' to it inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tons of ways to do this task some approach are here:
If you want to save your list in a text file like this `['006919', '006469', '005084', '004600', '006945']` so try this approach:

```
import random
fixed = "00"
resultList = []
for i in range(5):
    r = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    num = fixed + r
    resultList.append(num)
    print(num)
with open('resultFile.txt', 'w') as file_object:
    file_object.write(str(resultList))
```

Another way is to store each random variable line by line in a text file so you can refer to these approaches:

**First method:**

```
import random
fixed = "00"
resultList = []
for i in range(5):
    r = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    num = fixed + r
    resultList.append(num)
    print(num)
with open('resultFile.txt', 'w') as file_object:
    for item in resultList:
        file_object.write("%s\n" % item)
```

**Second Method:**
You can directly put all random numbers in file one by one when generating a random number like this:

```
import random
fixed = "00"
resultList = []
with open('resultFile.txt', 'w') as file_object:
    for i in range(5):
        r = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
        num = fixed + r
        file_object.write("%s\n" % item)
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. Naively you can construct a list with `list.append`

```py
fixed = '00'

results = []

for _ in range(5):
    r = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    num = fixed+r
    results.append(num)
```

Or, more simply, wrap this all in a function and use a list comprehension

```py
def generate_random_number(fixed):
    r = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    return f"{fixed}{r}"  # f-strings like this are valid in Python 3.6+

results = [generate_random_number('00') for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: note that I replaced your `for i in range(5)` with `for _ in range(5)` here. This is a common idiom when you don't really care about your loop variable, and just want to execute the block a certain number of times.

Answer (score 0):

For the leading zeros you can also use format. Put the strings in a list and then write them to a file. You can access the variables with results[0] ... results[4].

```
import random

results = []

for _ in range(5):
    results.append('{:06d}'.format(random.randint(1000, 9999)))

print(results)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
    for res in results:
        file.write(res + '\n')
```

Contents of result.txt:

```
003066
003712
009108
008017
009314
```